# Cloning GitHub Repositories

Tags: github

I've created a VM on Windows 10 to run Ubuntu, in the VM cloning GitHub repositories worked without any problems. Because of resource limitations the VM did not perform so I installed Ubuntu as an OS on another PC. Now in the OS cloning the same GitHub repositories previously cloned in the VM is asking for Usernames and Passwords, why is that and and how can I overcome this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: This isn't an Ubuntu question. You need to read up on Github authentication: SSH keys

Answer (score 0):

I don't know everything about your windows setup, but it might have already had the authentication it needed when the VM was setup, but that authentication doesn't carry over to your new setup.

You have two options in front of you: one, you can setup an ssh key and clone via ssh: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent

Two, you can use `gh` instead, which provides an authentication like a graphical interface. Here's the documentation on how to install it: https://github.com/cli/cli/blob/trunk/docs/install_linux.md

and then you run `gh auth login` and follow the instructions to setup your login info.